# How to create equivalent date format for 'MMM dd, yyyy K:mm:ss aaa' in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, date-formatting

I need to convert a date to the following format in XSLT 2.0.

```
MMM dd, yyyy K:mm:ss aaa
Dec 14, 2013 11:59:59 PM
```

That format string is for Java with the locale/calendar en_US. How can I get the same result in XSLT with the date-format function?

---

I have tried the following, but it doesn't give me exactly what I need and don't know how to fix it.

```
format-dateTime(//date, '[Mn] [D], [Y] [h]:[m01]:[s01] [PN]', 'en', (), ())
december 14, 2013 11:59:59 P.M.
```

---

Finally figured out that `[MNn,*-3]` gives me the correct month. But still don't get how to get rid of the dots in PM...

---

Not happy about it, but as a (hopefully) temporary workaround I have simply added another step where I do `replace($formattedDateString, '[.]', '')`. Works in this case since there are no other dots in the date string, but not pretty...

Comment: Ah, yes. A replace works too and probably simpler than testing the hours...

Answer (score 1):

Note that you could use the `fn:hours-from-dateTime()` to extract the hour and based on that generate your own AM or PM text.

It is not unlikely also that the format string is somewhat specific to the XLST processor you're using. The format is not extremely well defined for such things. (i.e. Could you get them in lowercase?)

Comment: I can get them in lowercase by swapping `[PN]` with `[Pn]`, so that's all per the specification. What's not is the dots, which I cannot see anywhere. All the examples use the same as I, but display no dots. ([XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-date) 16.5.3)